# Android screen pressure support

Tags: android

I'd like to know if a specific device (or screen) supports reporting of touch pressure.

Googled, searched stackoverflow and nothing.

Also looked at both MotionEvent and android.*.Display.

You can infer support from MotionEvent.getPressure() obviously, but I'd like to know capability. I can imagine an edge case where no pressure is reported but the screen supports it.

android.view.Display has some information but nothing related to pressure.

android.hardware.Display has nothing useful.

Comment: It appears to involve the class [InputDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice), but I can't figure out how to use this class for that purpose.