# Determining whether a screen is pressure-sensitive

Tags: android, touchscreen, pressure

How do I query for the features that an Android touchscreen supports? In particular, I want to know whether yet-to-be-received input on the screen will emit values for pressure, major axis width, and minor axis width.

I'm not doing this to limit my app to installation on specific devices, but instead to test my software, which detects specialized gestures. I know that I can determine whether the device has emitted axes or pressure upon receiving input, but I'm generated log files in advance of testing that need to report expectations during the test (to simplify things a bit).

The answer to this question appears to involve the [InputDevice class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice), but I don't see how to use this class to get the information.

(Note: I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406221/android-screen-pressure-support), but mine is more general: determining the features supported by the device's screen. People might also dismiss that question because the determination can be made after receiving input.)

Comment: All the Android devices I am currently aware of (since 2008) are **capacitive**. They work by sensing *proximity*, not *pressure*.

Comment: Thanks @Fantômas. That may be the case -- I haven't yet used one supporting pressure -- but the [API itself](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int)) claims to support pressure. In any case, my solution is not dependent on the existence of pressure, but gives added advantages when it is there. So I still would like to detect it, in case such devices do exist.

Comment: I'm also seeing devices that do not support distinct major and minor axes, and other devices that do. So that's another feature I'd like to detect prior to input.

Comment: You may try to get the pressure and eventually handle the error

Comment: It's too late by then. I'm laying ground work in the log header, and I don't want the added complexity of generating the log header only after the first input is received -- all for not knowing how to get device characteristics. And I'd need a non-trivial sampling to conclude that major and minor axes are not independent. (FYI, no error is reported -- I just get pressure == 0.)

Comment: So, when the pressure is 0, nothing happens. If it's between 0 and 1 you can handle the returned value.